# SLIM SQL запрос

Tags: php, sql, slim

Здравствуйте имеется SQL запрос:

```
SELECT id, region, autonom, area, city, city_2 FROM locality 
WHERE ((region LIKE ? and autonom is null and area is null and city is null and city_2 is null) 
or (city LIKE ? and city_2 is null) 
or(city_2 LIKE ?))
```

По сути это запрос ищет по полному совпадению. Мне нужно чтобы, если значение содержало строку, то выдавало результат (используется %).

К какой части % можно приделать?

Я пробовал в SQL засунуть (?+%; ?+'%')

в bind_param засунуть ($query+'%')

Везде вылазиют ошибки.

Код

```
function getAllCities($query){
        $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT id, region, autonom, area, city, city_2 FROM locality WHERE ((region LIKE ? and autonom is null and area is null and city is null and city_2 is null) or (city LIKE ? and city_2 is null) or(city_2 LIKE ?))");
        $stmt-> bind_param("sss", $query, $query, $query);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($id, $region, $autonom, $area, $city, $city_2);
        $cities = array();
        while($stmt->fetch()){
            $temp = array();
            $temp['id'] = $id;
            $temp['region'] = $region;
            $temp['autonom'] = $autonom;
            $temp['area'] = $area;            
            $temp['city'] = $city;
            $temp['city_2'] = $city_2;
            array_push($cities, $temp);
        }
        return $cities;
    }
```

Варианты:  `bind_param("sss", $query+'%', $query+'%', $query+'%');` - Не срабатывает %

region LIKE ?+'%' and.... - Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param()

region LIKE ?+% and ..... Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param()

bind_param("sss", $query+%, $query+%, $query+%) - syntax error

Comment: Ошибки-то мы угадать должны? Или может текстом ошибок поделитесь?

Comment: @u_mulder добавил код

Comment: Из джаваскрипта что ли пришли? Конкатенация в php это точка `.`.

Comment: Не совсем понял вас. Если вы про bind_param("sss", $query.'%',...) или bind_param("sss", $query.%,...), то эти варианты выдают ошибку синтасиса

Comment: А в ошибке синтаксиса что пишут конкретно?

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference in ; syntax error, unexpected '%' соответственно

Comment: Это 2 ошибки, к каждому из вариантов

Answer (score 0):

Все, что требуется изменить:

```
$stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT id, region, autonom, area, city, city_2 FROM locality WHERE ((region LIKE ? and autonom is null and area is null and city is null and city_2 is null) or (city LIKE ? and city_2 is null) or (city_2 LIKE ?))");

// требуется потому, что аргументы в `bind_param` передаются по ссылке
$query .= '%';   

$stmt->bind_param("sss", $query, $query, $query);
```